# How to specify the version for drush site-install

Tags: drush, installation

I am running drush site-install and I want to install d6 but d7 is default, how to I specify the Drupal version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I use `drush dl drupal` then cd into the drupal directory and then `drush si [other parameters]`.

That means, when you download drupal core you need to specify the version at that time -- not during site installation (which is just running the files).

You can do that by appending the version onto your dl argument, for example:
`drush dl drupal-6` or `drush dl drupal-6.x`

Comment: OK, well just running drupal si actually gets version 7 so I thought you could actually choose the version

Comment: I see the confusion. `drush help si` lists all the options site-install can take, it doesnt appear to a version option. A similiar issue applies to updating an installed module from say 1.x to -dev you just do `drush dl modulename -dev` and then `drush updb`. If you just `drush dl module` drush assumes you mean "whatever version is most stable". Drush leaves it to you essentially to figure out a workflow for non-current or -dev stuff.